# Troubleshooting PCB with ATMEGA32U4

Tags: atmega32u4

I recently designed my very first PCB around the ATMEGA32U4-MU.
Unfortunately the chip isn't recognized when connecting the board to my computer via USB.

The LED turns on however, so the power section seems fine.
I didn't add any debugging capabilities to my board - dumb I know - , mainly because I was
counting on the spec, that says that the ATMEGA32U4 comes pre-flashed with USB DFU Bootloader.

Did I make any obvious mistakes in the schematic when connecting the microcontroller?   I appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both UCAP and UVCC are disconnected.

You seem to want a design which requires  the 3.3V to be connected to UCAP.

Comment: Good point, thanks. UCAP is connected to ground via capacitor C8 (1u) according to the spec. UVCC is indeed disconnected - shouldn't it rather be connected to 5V from USB, same as VBus? I'm trying to run it on 3.3V.

Comment: No, there is two ways and my fix is what you want because you are running it with external 3.3V regulator. Look at the power diagrams in the data sheet. If you want to run MCU at 5V then you would feed VBUS to UVCC and there will then be internal regulator giving out 3.3V to UCAP.